# Program using ceil() in C

Tags: c, ceil

I did the following code using ceil()

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>    
int main()
{
  float val;
  float cVal;

  val=23.4;

  cVal =ceil(val);
  printf("ceil value:%f\n",cVal);
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting th following error
In function `main':
test1.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to`ceil'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What is wrong in this code??Please help!

I compiled it using makefile

```
>>cmake .
>>make
>>./hello.out
```

Comment: What compiler and toolchain are you using? What command did you use to build it?

Comment: add `-lm` (for `libmath`) to your compile string. Notice the `"Link with -lm."` in [man 3 ceil](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ceil.3.html) Nothing wrong with your code, but there is something missing in your compile options.

Comment: Including the error message is a good thing, but try to google it yourself. When I searched for "undefined reference to ceil" I found the answer immediately.

Comment: I complied it using make file..>>cmake .  >>make >>/hello.out @Dai

Answer (score 1):

From https://askubuntu.com/a/745199/513302

> If you are going to compile a C program with `math.h` library in Linux using `gcc` you will have to use `–lm` option in the compiler command-line

```
gcc xyz.c -o xyz -lm
```

The `-lm` option is actually `-l` (for "link a module") and `m` is shorthand for the built-in math library.

Comment: I compiled it using a make file